# Resizing of JQuery.ui tab with nested table

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-ui, tabs

I am using JQuery.ui to create tabs on my website. One of the tabs have a nested Table, that I use to organize the elements on the tab (Namely, a text-input and a button in the first row, and an JQuery.ui Accordion and a Google Map)

When I load the page, it's all beautiful and shiny, but if I resize the browser window, it seems that the table inside the tab doesn't resize in the same manner that the tab. The tab shrinks more than the table, so my Map and the Accordion start do overflow the bottom of the Tab.

I hope I have made the problem clear. Does anyone have any idea of what can be causing this issue?

Comment: Please post some code here or link an online example.

Comment: Ok, posting and online example.

Comment: Can't edit my own question it seems? Well, here it is -> http://mapnet.vesica.com.br:8000/bnp/. Currently running on a homemade server, I'm going to upload it into a stable one later today.